# Удаление записи из таблицы без использования GET

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Обычная страница, обычная ссылка, с адресом типа `*.php?n=180`. Ведет на страницу, которая вылавливает переменную (методом GET), и удаляет из нужной таблицы определенную запись. Само собой, если ввести в строчку адреса `*.php?n=число`, то удаление тоже срабатывает.

Подскажите, как правильно организовать удаление записи, чтобы простым вписыванием в строку браузера удалить нельзя было?

Comment: Передавайте методом POST! Соответственно и проверку делайте на POST запрос.

Comment: Никак!

Авторизация и права доступа!

Comment: методом POST без проблем, но что же это получается, лепить форму, только так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проверять, чтоб страница удаляла, только если авторизован тот, кому положенно.
2. Как защита от случайных срабатываний - то обычно делается ссылка вида del.php?n=1&rand=123456
   Где rand перегенерится при каждом обращении (а главное! при самом удалении) и пишется в сессию на стороне сервера. И проверять, чтоб то что прислали, сходилось с тем, что есть в сессии.
3. А самое страшное, это сделать промежуточную страницу со страшным вопросом "Точно удалить?". Ссылка "ДА" делается по методу описанному в П.2 (со случайным ключиком).